# Copying one NSString into other one Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsstring

I have a problem in Xcode.I am trying to copy one NSString into other one but is not working.

The original NSString **pageTitle** is on the RestViewController:
This is my RestViewContoller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Restaurant.h"

@interface RestViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Restaurant *DetailModal;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pageTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pageDescription;

@end
```

The NSString I want to save the data is on the RestViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Restaurant *DetailModal;
```

but is a Restaurant class type.

My Restaurant class is:
Restaurant.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Restaurant : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *desc;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *image;

- (instancetype)init:(NSString *)title descripiton:(NSString *)description image:(NSString *)image;

@end
```

Restaurant.m:

```
#import "Restaurant.h"

@implementation Restaurant

- (instancetype)init:(NSString *)title descripiton:(NSString *)description image:(NSString *)image {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.title = title;
        self.desc = description;
        self.image = image;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And finally the place where I want to copy this NSStrings is my RestViewController.m:

```
  #import "RestViewController.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @interface RestViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation RestViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _pageTitle = @"Test";
            _DetailModal.title = _pageTitle;
            NSLog(@"_DetailModal.title: %@", _DetailModal.title);
    }

    @end
```

The problem is when I see the result of the

> NSLog(@"_DetailModal.title: %@", _DetailModal.title);`on the console,
>   it puts me:`2016-11-21 11:42:05.407 MadEat[3667:104028]
>   _DetailModal.title: (null)

What can I do? I know I have a low level of Xcode, but I need your help please. Thank you very much.

Comment: did you checked the content of _pageTitle ?

Comment: where do you set the _pageTitle?

Comment: you cannot pass any value from your RestViewController. is _DetailModal become local their and doesnot contain global value. How you are switching from one controller to another

Comment: @PrafukD Sorry I forget to set it when I was writing the question

Comment: @NarendraPandey and there is not any way to solve it? It is impossible to copy? Thank you!

Comment: in that case why you don't make Your NSString as a global Variable. that can solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initailize the instance of DataModel First.

Then proceed with assignment

```
_DetailModal = [[DetailModal alloc] init:_pageTitle descripiton:@"Desc" image:@"image"];
```

There is a instance method defined already to do the task.

After this also you can alter the value by

```
_DetailModal.title = @"title_of_yours"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use detailmodal, you must alloc the restaurant class object (detailmodal). Then only the objects can be used.

```
detailmodal=[[restaurant alloc]init];
detailmodal.title=_pagetitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use a object, you have to create it first.

```
DetailModal *detailModal = [DetailModal new];
```

That way the object will be created and values stored to the class properties will be reserved.

Comment: I would expect it to crash before even trying to print anything if it wasnt allocated

Comment: It did, in earlier versions of Xcode. Nowadays it just 'ignores' as if all actions towards the non-allocated object. It are hard bugs to find in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
_DetailModal.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: _pageTitle];
```

(Did not test this)

Comment: This is in case that Vincent's answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

plz chek you _DetailModal is not **nil**

if it's **nil** then

first you need to alloc the memory for you DetailModal Class object

like this

```
DetailModal *detailModal = [DetailModal new];
```

then after set the value you want

```
 detailModal.title = _pageTitle;
```